# Setter Method of Bean Class

Tags: java, javabeans

Hello Friends Iam trying to call Setter method from other Setter method but iam getting nullPointerException in that. Is possible to call setter method from other setter.

Here is my bean class:-

```
public class ApplicationParameterListEntityTo{
private Long statusValueID;    
private WidgetFieldValueBean1 parameterListStatusValueID;

public Long getStatusValueID() {
    return statusValueID;
}

public void setStatusValueID(Long statusValueID){
    this.statusValueID = statusValueID;
    this.parameterListStatusValueID.setWidgetFieldValueID(statusValueID);
}
public WidgetFieldValueBean1 getParameterListStatusValueID() {
    return parameterListStatusValueID;
}
```

Is there any problem in this peace of code.

Comment: Where do you initialize this `WidgetFieldValueBean1 parameterListStatusValueID;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line probably is giving you null pointer

```
  this.parameterListStatusValueID.setWidgetFieldValueID(statusValueID);
```

Because, the `WidgetFieldValueBean1 parameterListStatusValueID` object is not initialized before you are calling the `setWidgetFieldValueId` method

You need to do something like

```
this.parameterListStatusValueID = new WidgetFieldValueBean1 ();//Considering it has a default constructor
 this.parameterListStatusValueID.setWidgetFieldValueID(statusValueID);
```

Comment: Thanks I was stuck in this for so long :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `setStatusValueID` method. Since `parameterListStatusValueID` is never initialized, it is `null`, and thus every access to it (like this method, e.g., does), will result in a `NullPointerExcetpion`.

One way to solve this would be to initialize it in the definition:

```
public class ApplicationParameterListEntityTo {
    private Long statusValueID;    
    private WidgetFieldValueBean1 parameterListStatusValueID = new WidgetFieldValueBean1();

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the member variable `parameterListStatusValueID`, such as:

```
private WidgetFieldValueBean1 parameterListStatusValueID = new WidgetFieldValueBean1();
```